# Update list of tuples in python

Tags: python, nlp, tuples

I have a dataframe where each row is a list of tuples, such as

```
[('This', 'DET'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('example', 'NOUN'), ('text', 'NOUN'), ('that', 'DET'), ('I', 'PRON'), ('use', 'VERB'), ('in', 'ADP'), ('order', 'NOUN'), ('to', 'PART'), ('get', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('answer', 'NOUN')]
```

Then, in each row, I mark the words of some tuples with `<IN>word</IN>` or `<TA>word</TA>`. For example:

```
updated_word : <IN>example</IN>
updated_word  : <TA>answer</TA>
```

I want to update each row of the dataframe so that it contains the updated version of my tuples, and have something like :

```
[('This', 'DET'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('<IN>example</IN>', 'NOUN'), ('text', 'NOUN'), ('that', 'DET'), ('I', 'PRON'), ('use', 'VERB'), ('in', 'ADP'), ('order', 'NOUN'), ('to', 'PART'), ('get', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('<TA>answer</TA>', 'NOUN')]
```

I have managed to update each tuple separately, but I cannot find a way to append them to the dataframe row and have the updated **list of tuples** per row. Can someone help me?

Here is the code:

```python
cols = list(df.columns)[4:]
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    doc = nlp(row['title'])
    pos_tags = [(token.text, token.pos_) for token in doc if not token.pos_ == "PUNCT"]

    for position, tuple_ in enumerate(pos_tags, start=1):
        word = tuple_[0]
        spacy_pos_tag = tuple_[1]
        word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
        for col in cols:
           if position in row[col]:
              word = f'<{col.upper()}>{word}</{col.upper()}>'
           else:
              word = word
         new_text.append(' '.join(word))
         tuple_ = (word, spacy_pos_tag)
        pos_tags[position] = tuple_
df['title'] = pos_tags
print(df.title)
```

**UPDATE**

I used @Peter White 's suggestion to get the list of tuples, but I still get an error when I want to append each pos_tags list of tuples into each row of my dataframe column named `df['title']`. The error message is :

```
    raise ValueError(
 ValueError: Length of values (23) does not match length of index (500)
```

Comment: did you try pos_tags[position] = tuple_? at the end where the print is?

Comment: `pos_tags[position] = tuple_`  
 `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: remove the start=1 from enumerate. It is counting from 1 instead of 0, so that the very end, it is trying to access an element 1 greater than the list size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put pos_tags[position] = tuple_? at the end, and remove the start=1 from enumerate:

```
cols = list(df.columns)[4:]
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    doc = nlp(row['title'])
    pos_tags = [(token.text, token.pos_) for token in doc if not token.pos_ == "PUNCT"]

    for position, tuple_ in enumerate(pos_tags):
        word = tuple_[0]
        spacy_pos_tag = tuple_[1]
        word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
        for col in cols:
           if position in row[col]:
              word = f'<{col.upper()}>{word}</{col.upper()}>'
           else:
              word = word
         new_text.append(' '.join(word))
         tuple_ = (word, spacy_pos_tag)
         print(tuple_)
         pos_tags[position] = tuple_
```

Comment: Hi, can you please check my updated question ? I used your suggestion, but when I am trying to put each list of tuples in each row of my dataframe column, I get this value error

Comment: I think you have a lot of token.pos_ == "PUNCT", which you have filtered out, so now they don't have equal lengths. You could try moving that part into the for loop, so that you don't modify those rows but still keep them in the final result